# Поиск по части выражения в Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

В своем проекте я использую Spring Data.

В БД есть таблица с полем name - varchar. Надо реализовать поиск по части слова для автозаполнения. Например ввожу первые две буквы "Mi" и в ответ получаю 10 значений из БД в которых присутствует эти 2 буквы в таком порядке.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого в SQL используется [LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) оператор, который использует символ процента '%' (и подчеркивания '_') для задания шаблона (маски) поиска.

В Spring Data JPA ему соответствуют [ключевые слова](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) `Like`, `NotLike`, `StartingWith`, `EndingWith`, `Containing`. Удобнее всего использовать последние три (т.к. первые два не используют маску - ее нужно задавать вручную).

Таким образом, можно сделать такие методы в репозитории:

```
public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findByNameStartingWith(String name);
    List<Person> findByNameEndingWith(String name);
    List<Person> findByNameContaining(String name);
}
```

Если при поиске необходимо игнорировать регистр, то к методу нужно добавить ключевое слово `IgnoreCase`:

```
List<Person> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);
```

Тоже самое можно реализовать самостоятельно, при помощи SQL ([JPQL](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html)/[HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql)):

```
@Query("select p from Person p where upper(p.name) like concat('%', upper(?1), '%')")
List<Person> findWithQuery(String name);
```

Comment: Спасибо. То, что надо. А получить только 10 записей можно таким же образом, или придется sql писать?

Comment: Смотрим сюда: [limit-query-result](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result). A sql/jpql/hql, использовать будет не очень удобно - т.к. jpql/hql не поддерживают `limit` и `offset`, они есть только в нативном sql, следовательно зависят от его диалекта. Вообще говоря, для ограничения выборки я бы посоветовал использовать [пагинацию](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts): `Page<Person> findByNameContaining(String name, Pageable pageable);`

Answer (score 4):

Объявить в [репозитории](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) метод `List<Person> findByNameLike(String name)` и вызывать его в коде осуществляющем поиск.